# How to efficiently combine user authentication with token authentication?

Tags: postgresql, authentication

What is the most efficient approach of authentication, considering an user based authentication system combined with a token based authentication system?

For this question please consider the following tables:

```
create table users (
  id int generated always as identity primary key,
  username text not null unique,
  password text not null
);

create table tokens (
  id int generated always as identity primary key,
  user_id int not null references users(id),
  access_token text unique default generate_random_token(),
  refresh_token text default generate_random_token(),
  updated_on timestamp with time zone default current_timestamp,
  created_on timestamp with time zone default current_timestamp
);
```

As far as I know to create an user and allow it to authenticate the following steps are mandatory (explained with query statements):

1. Optional: Create an user record.

   ```
   insert into users (username, password) values ('foo', create_password_hash('bar'));
   ```
2. Check if the user can authenticate itself and remember the user's ID:

   ```
   select * from users where username = 'foo' and password = validate_password_hash('bar', password);
   ```
3. Check if the user has an existing token and hand over the access_token:

   ```
   select access_token from tokens where user_id = 123;
   ```
4. Optional: Create a token if the user doesn't have one yet:

   ```
   insert into tokens (user_id) values (123) returning access_token;
   ```

If my assumption for the steps to be taken is right, then I wonder how to minimize these four statements into a single one or have at least some guidance how this could be done more efficient. Also I could imagine that my approach for this use case incorrect and that there is an other more efficient approach, please let me know.

---

**BONUS**

Perhaps your approach could also cover the process of refreshing a token. Considering the approach explained above the refresh should only occur when a token is found at the third step and according to the `updated_on` timestamp the token is "expired".

Comment: You want to create an account, or login to an account, without knowing ahead of time which you are doing?  That sounds like a disaster.  Really, how efficient does this need to be?

Comment: @jjanes I guess step one can also be optional, would that make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this use case is fairly specific and thus it is quite a challenge to write an "upsert" statement what covers all the steps as described in the question. Therefor I see the following procedure as the only way out.

```
create or replace function user_auth(p_user text, p_pass text)
returns token_response as
$$
declare
    v_user_id bigint;
    v_token_id bigint;
    v_updated_on timestamp with time zone;
    v_access_token text;
    v_refresh_token text;
begin
    select id
    into v_user_id
    from users
    where username = p_user
        and password = validate_password_hash(p_pass, password)
    limit 1;

    if (v_user_id is not null) then
        select id, updated_on, access_token, refresh_token
        into v_token_id, v_updated_on, v_access_token, v_refresh_token
        from tokens
        where user_id = v_user_id
        order by updated_on desc
        limit 1;

        if (v_token_id is null) then
            insert into tokens (user_id)
            values (v_user_id)
            returning access_token, refresh_token
            into v_access_token, v_refresh_token;
        end if;

        if (v_updated_on < current_timestamp - interval '1 day') then
            update tokens
            set access_token = generate_random_token(),
                refresh_token = generate_random_token(),
                updated_on = current_timestamp
            where id = v_token_id
            returning access_token, refresh_token
            into v_access_token, v_refresh_token;
        end if;
    end if;

    return (v_access_token, v_refresh_token)::token_response;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

[Here is a working DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e75f0b327b5b7c8a5defc183fe7f3337)